# Canvas Size Issue on Android Tablet Chrome 27

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have following code to draw line on canvas.

in HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.moveTo(0,0);
   ctx.lineTo(200,100);
   ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

The line is not drawing on canvas. If I change width and height of the canvas to '200' working fine.

**Note:** Issue on Android Tablet Chrome 27.0

test code link: http://jsbin.com/qerepige/1/edit

Any reason/suggestion there to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the ctx.lineTo?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(300,200);
  ctx.stroke();
</script>
```